# Get the ID of dynamic Views in android

Tags: android

I retrieve data from the internet. I add the views dynamically to a layout. I get the ID and the name :

```
for (int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++) {
                TextView tv[] = new TextView[productsList.size()];
                tv[i] = new TextView(LoveActivity.this);
                tv[i].setText(String.valueOf(productsList.get(i).get("name")));
                tv[i].setTextColor(R.color.black);
                tv[i].setId(Integer.parseInt(productsList.get(i).get("id")));
                ID = tv[i].getId();
                tv[i].setOnClickListener(LoveActivity.this);
                linearLayoutWithData.addView(tv[i]);
            }
```

Now I want to set the ID of an added view to the ID which I get from the internet. To check this I use:

```
ID = tv[i].getId();
```

But ID become always the size of the Array..
Thanks for replying :-)

Comment: what is the "id" field supposed to be, a hash? also what is ID, it is reset each time you loop through the productsList

Answer (score 0):

In every Iteration of your loop the variable `ID` gets overwritten. So the ID you receive after the loop is finished is the ID of the last view you added.

Comment: And how can I get the ID of each view?

Comment: @FabASP For example by storing all the IDs in a list? Depends pretty much on what you want to do with the IDs.

Comment: The ID is the primary key in a mysql database. The ID shall identify the name and I want to hand over the ID via Intent to an another activity :-)
Can you give me an example?